# OnItemClickListener does not work in ListView in Fragments

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

Android Code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View rootView;

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_contact_list, container, false);

        listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Log.d("Contact List", "Before read method");

        ReadContacts();

        Log.d("Contact List", "After Read Method");

        Log.d("Before ", "Before Adapter Initialization");

        adapter = new ContactListAdapter(getActivity(), contact_list);

        Log.d("After",
                "After Adapter Initializaiton and before listview set adapter");

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                TextView name = (TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
                TextView phone = (TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvContactPhone);

                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        "Name : " + name.getText().toString() + "Phone : "
                                + phone.getText().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        return rootView;

}
```

The adapter is working properly and i can see the data in a listview but i cannot click on the list items. There is no response

i have set the android:clickable = "true"

The fragment is a part of a view Pager

I cannot use list fragments and want to use an adapter .. what is the error ?

I have also pasted this setonitemclick method in onActivityCreated() .. it didnt work

XML of List View :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
     >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Adapter I am using:

```
package com.example.eh;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

  public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {


 Context context;
 List<Tuple> contact_list=new ArrayList<Tuple>();



public ContactListAdapter(Context ctx, List<Tuple> data)
{
    context = ctx;
    contact_list = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return contacts.size();
    return contact_list.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return contact_list.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public String getName(int arg0)
{
    return contact_list.get(arg0).getContactName();
}

public String getPhone(int arg0)
{
    return contact_list.get(arg0).getContactPhone();

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        view = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_full_contact_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(getName(position));
    holder.phone.setText(getPhone(position));

    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name;
    public TextView phone;
    public Button invite;

    public ViewHolder(View v)
    {
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
        phone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvContactPhone);
        invite = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bInviteFriends);
    }

  }

 }
```

The XML of the row item:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/LeftSide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContactName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:maxLines="1"         

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContactPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvContactName"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bInviteFriends"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Invite" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your XML of both view, Main and RowView.

Comment: are you set onclicklistener on Button??

Comment: no setonclicklisterer is on ITEM of listview .. i have listview.setonItemClick

Answer (score 0):

Have you put a `breakpoint` inside the `onItemClick` method to make sure its not fired?

Try to add this line of code on your `listview's` XML :

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: I haven't put any break point, all i am doing is displaying a toast onitemclick

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),position.toString+" is the position you clicked!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TextView name = (TextView) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
            TextView phone = (TextView) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvContactPhone);

            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                    "Name : " + name.getText().toString() + "Phone : "
                            + phone.getText().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```